# deleting local branches forked from a repo

Tags: git, github

```
$ git branch --all
* 1.1/develop
  remotes/origin/1.0/develop
  remotes/origin/1.0/master
  remotes/origin/1.1/develop
  remotes/origin/1.1/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/1.1/develop
```

I tried

`$ git branch -d remotes/origin/1.0/develop

error: branch 'remotes/origin/1.0/develop' not found.`

but it can't find it. How do I delete all the branches except the current one?

__

EDIT: I tried this and the branch was deleted.

`$ git branch -d -r origin/1.1/master

Deleted remote branch origin/1.1/master (was 834f5e0).`

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't specifically `pull` the remote branches, they'll exist on your machine as a [remote-tracking branch](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/09/remote-tracking-branches.html).

To delete a remote tracking branch from your repository use the command `git branch -d -r <remote-name>/<branch-name>`

Comment: i simply cloned it, `git clone --recursive giturl.git name`

Comment: `--recursive` doesn't pull all the branches... it just pulls `submodules` if you're using them

Comment: I only want to delete the branches from my local machine, since it's not my own repo. yes I downloaded its submodules.

Comment: In that case you don't need to do anything. Since you never `pull`ed out the remote branch it doesn't exist on your machine. BTW, the command above *will* delete the remote branch so don't use it if that's not your intention.

Comment: but how come they exist when i do `git branch --all`

Comment: "-a , --all List both **remote-tracking branches** and local branches."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10867/discussion-between-michael-and-jack-spairow)